# How to use kevin murphy toolkit for OCR using HMM?

Tags: matlab, ocr, hidden-markov-models

I want to recognise English alphabets using a hidden Markov model. I have extracted features using the zoning method.

For each alphabet, I have got a 20*10 matrix of features using zoning because I have 20 types of characters and divided it into 10 vertical zones and found out density.

What will be the observation matrix, transition matrix and emission matrix ?
What must be kept in prior0, transmat0 and obsmat0 ?

Comment: The priors and transition matrix need to be trained, while the observation matrix is your input.

Comment: What do you mean by training prior and transition matrix. What are the values that must be given to prior and transition matrix ?